# Ef Core insert entity with relationship

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, ef-core-3.0

I am having issues with ef core 3.1 and sql server inserting a entity with a relationship.

my entity I want to insert is a player with a country relationship

```
public class Player{
        [Key]
        public Guid Id {get;set;}
        [ForeignKey("Country")]
        public int CountryId { get; set; }
        public Country Country { get; set; } 
        ...
}
public class Country{
        [key]
        public int Id {get;set;}
        public string Name {get;set;}
        ...
}
```

I want to insert it by setting the CountryId to an existing country id and I want to be able to insert it by adding the full country entity and not the id (having it insert both)

is it possible to do this without loading the full country entity and setting the Player.Country = country or is that something that is required to get the relationship?

currently the way it is being done i get some json with the player and countryId then using my db context do a simple _context.Player.Add(player) followed by _context.SaveCahnges().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> by adding the full country entity and not the id (having it insert both)

I think you are misunderstand this: In the database, there is only the `CountryId`. The `Country` entity is not saved directly in the `Player` table but just a reference to the country using its id.

So you have two options to set the country on the player. By assigning a country id directly:

```
player.CountryId = someCountryId;
```

Or by assigning the country entity from your database:

```
player.Country = existingCountry;
```

In order for the latter one to work, the country entity needs to be *tracked* by EntityFramework. This usually means that you will have to load it from the database.

If you want to provide an API to create a player, then just passing the country id is usually the more flexible approach.